# Is it it true to say that all critical points must be either extrema or a saddle point?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I want to be very clear and explicit about this. Is it it true to say that all critical points **must** be either extrema or a saddle point?

In other words, if we find that $f'(x) = 0$ or $f'(x) = D.N.E$, there are 2 and **only** 2 possibilities:

1. $f(x)$ is an extrema.
2. $f(x)$ is a saddle point.

There are no other possibilities.

Is this true or false? Thank you.

Comment: Let $f(x)=x$ for a $x \in [0,1]$, and $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}$ at $x \in [1,2]$ (draw the picture) you get a sharp turn at 1, so the derivative is undefined, but it is neither a saddle point nor an extrema.

Comment: @mb- You're right. Thank you.

Comment: What is a saddle point?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg A critical point that is neither a local maximum nor a local minimum.

Comment: Although it's (unfortunately) common in single-variable calculus to call a point of non-differentiability a critical point, I've never seen this done in multivariable calculus. A saddle point should be defined to be a point so that no matter how close you look nearby, there are points where the function is higher and points where the function is lower. I personally want the function to be differentiable, too, but ... OK.

Comment: The Pointer: with your definition, of course a point is either an extremum or a "saddle point". As @Ted correctly points out, that definition is not very reasonable. A saddle point  might be a critical point such that the quadratic term in its Taylor development (corresponding to the Hesssian matrix) is non-degenerate but neither definite positive nor negative definite. (Ted's more general definition does not require non-degeneracy however, and since  he knows these things very well, you should probably adopt his definition rather than mine)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Unfortunately, these are definitions straight from my course material. Perhaps you and Ted should be my professors instead. :) Hopefully the true definition gets explained in more advanced courses.

Comment: Dear Pointer, having Ted as a professor is certainly a privilege for any student...(I have never met him in reality but his courses on YouTube are fantastic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=x^2$ for rational $x$, otherwise $f(x)=-x^2$. We have $f'(x)=0$, but $f$ has neither an extremum nor a saddle in $x=0$.